# How to run certain Processes depending on user input and then destroy them accordingly?

Tags: java, process, arraylist, user-input, runtime.exec

So for example:

`Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();` creates `Runtime rt`

`Process p1 = rt.exec("C:/Windows/System32/calc.exe");` creates `Process p1` on `Runtime rt`.

Then `p1.destroy();` will destroy `Process p1`.

My question is: If I have more than one `Process` (e.g. `p1`, `p2`, and `p3`), how do I `destroy()` them all at once, instead of having to destroy them one by one?

And for a list, how would I implement a list into my code? I have not yet worked with lists and arrays, although I have tried to learn how to use them, but I guess it's one of those things where being taught with an example is much easier...

Also, a `for-loop` to `destroy()` the processes has been mentioned to me, but how would I go about that with a `Process`?

Here is my code:

```
package tf2_account_chief;

import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.util.List;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class TF2_Account_Chief extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

    private static JFrame f = new JFrame("TF2 Account C.H.I.E.F.");

    private JLabel runL = new JLabel("Check box to run!");
    private JLabel runnableTogetherLabel = new JLabel("How many idlers would you like to run at a time?");
    private JCheckBox boxRun = new JCheckBox();
    private static JTextField runnableTogetherInput = new JTextField();
    private JButton runButton = new JButton("Run!");

    private static Image BGimg;

    private static int allSets, setsRun, runnableTogether, totalRunnable, run;

    private static int processesArray;


    private static final String dir = System.getProperty("user.dir");

        public void launchFrame() {

            f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            f.pack(); //Adjusts panel to components for display
            f.setVisible(true);

            f.add(runL);
            f.add(boxRun);
            f.add(runnableTogetherInput);
            f.add(runnableTogetherLabel);
            f.add(runButton);

            f.setSize(500, 500);
            runL.setSize(500, 50);
            boxRun.setSize(20, 15);
            runnableTogetherInput.setSize(25, 15);
            runnableTogetherLabel.setSize(275, 25);
            runButton.setSize(60, 25);

            f.setLocation(0, 0);
            runL.setLocation(50, 50);
            boxRun.setLocation(95, 100);
            runnableTogetherInput.setLocation(285, 5);
            runnableTogetherLabel.setLocation(0, 0);
            runButton.setLocation(325, 0);

            boxRun.addActionListener(this);
            runButton.addActionListener(this);

}

        private void Processes() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();

            // "runnableTogether" will be the number that the user inputs in the GUI

            switch (runnableTogether) {

                case 128:
                    Process p128 = rt.exec(dir + "/run/Idle128.bat");
                case 127:
                    Process p127 = rt.exec(dir + "/run/Idle127.bat");
                case 126:
                    Process p126 = rt.exec(dir + "/run/Idle126.bat");
                case 125:
                    Process p125 = rt.exec(dir + "/run/Idle125.bat");
                case 124:
                    Process p124 = rt.exec(dir + "/run/Idle124.bat");
                case 123:
                    Process p123 = rt.exec(dir + "/run/Idle123.bat");
                case 122:
                    Process p122 = rt.exec(dir + "/run/Idle122.bat");
                case 121:
                    Process p121 = rt.exec(dir + "/run/Idle121.bat");
                case 120:
                    Process p120 = rt.exec(dir + "/run/Idle120.bat");
                case 119:
                    Process p119 = rt.exec(dir + "/run/Idle119.bat");
                case 118:
                    Process p118 = rt.exec(dir + "/run/Idle118.bat");
                case 117:
                    Process p117 = rt.exec(dir + "/run/Idle117.bat");
                case 116:
                    Process p116 = rt.exec(dir + "/run/Idle116.bat");
                case 115:
                    Process p115 = rt.exec(dir + "/run/Idle115.bat");
                case 114:
                    Process p114 = rt.exec(dir + "/run/Idle114.bat");
                case 113:
                    Process p113 = rt.exec(dir + "/run/Idle113.bat");
                case 112:
                    Process p112 = rt.exec(dir + "/run/Idle112.bat");
                case 111:
                    Process p111 = rt.exec(dir + "/run/Idle111.bat");
                case 110:
                    Process p110 = rt.exec(dir + "/run/Idle110.bat");
                case 109:
                    Process p109 = rt.exec(dir + "/run/Idle109.bat");
                case 108:
                    Process p108 = rt.exec(dir + "/run/Idle108.bat");
                case 107:
                    Process p107 = rt.exec(dir + "/run/Idle107.bat");
                case 106:
                    Process p106 = rt.exec(dir + "/run/Idle106.bat");
                case 105:
                    Process p105 = rt.exec(dir + "/run/Idle105.bat");
                case 104:
                    Process p104 = rt.exec(dir + "/run/Idle104.bat");
                case 103:
                    Process p103 = rt.exec(dir + "/run/Idle103.bat");
                case 102:
                    Process p102 = rt.exec(dir + "/run/Idle102.bat");
                case 101:
                    Process p101 = rt.exec(dir + "/run/Idle101.bat");
                case 100:
                    Process p100 = rt.exec(dir + "/run/Idle100.bat");
                case 99:
                    Process p99 = rt.exec(dir + "/run/Idle99.bat");
                case 98:
                    Process p98 = rt.exec(dir + "/run/Idle98.bat");
                case 97:
                    Process p97 = rt.exec(dir + "/run/Idle97.bat");
                case 96:
                    Process p96 = rt.exec(dir + "/run/Idle96.bat");
                case 95:
                    Process p95 = rt.exec(dir + "/run/Idle95.bat");
                case 94:
                    Process p94 = rt.exec(dir + "/run/Idle94.bat");
                case 93:
                    Process p93 = rt.exec(dir + "/run/Idle93.bat");
                case 92:
                    Process p92 = rt.exec(dir + "/run/Idle92.bat");
                case 91:
                    Process p91 = rt.exec(dir + "/run/Idle91.bat");
                case 90:
                    Process p90 = rt.exec(dir + "/run/Idle90.bat");
                case 89:
                    Process p89 = rt.exec(dir + "/run/Idle89.bat");
                case 88:
                    Process p88 = rt.exec(dir + "/run/Idle88.bat");
                case 87:
                    Process p87 = rt.exec(dir + "/run/Idle87.bat");
                case 86:
                    Process p86 = rt.exec(dir + "/run/Idle86.bat");
                case 85:
                    Process p85 = rt.exec(dir + "/run/Idle85.bat");
                case 84:
                    Process p84 = rt.exec(dir + "/run/Idle84.bat");
                case 83:
                    Process p83 = rt.exec(dir + "/run/Idle83.bat");
                case 82:
                    Process p82 = rt.exec(dir + "/run/Idle82.bat");
                case 81:
                    Process p81 = rt.exec(dir + "/run/Idle81.bat");
                case 80:
                    Process p80 = rt.exec(dir + "/run/Idle80.bat");
                case 79:
                    Process p79 = rt.exec(dir + "/run/Idle79.bat");
                case 78:
                    Process p78 = rt.exec(dir + "/run/Idle78.bat");
                case 77:
                    Process p77 = rt.exec(dir + "/run/Idle77.bat");
                case 76:
                    Process p76 = rt.exec(dir + "/run/Idle76.bat");
                case 75:
                    Process p75 = rt.exec(dir + "/run/Idle75.bat");
                case 74:
                    Process p74 = rt.exec(dir + "/run/Idle74.bat");
                case 73:
                    Process p73 = rt.exec(dir + "/run/Idle73.bat");
                case 72:
                    Process p72 = rt.exec(dir + "/run/Idle72.bat");
                case 71:
                    Process p71 = rt.exec(dir + "/run/Idle71.bat");
                case 70:
                    Process p70 = rt.exec(dir + "/run/Idle70.bat");
                case 69:
                    Process p69 = rt.exec(dir + "/run/Idle69.bat");
                case 68:
                    Process p68 = rt.exec(dir + "/run/Idle68.bat");
                case 67:
                    Process p67 = rt.exec(dir + "/run/Idle67.bat");
                case 66:
                    Process p66 = rt.exec(dir + "/run/Idle66.bat");
                case 65:
                    Process p65 = rt.exec(dir + "/run/Idle65.bat");
                case 64:
                    Process p64 = rt.exec(dir + "/run/Idle64.bat");
                case 63:
                    Process p63 = rt.exec(dir + "/run/Idle63.bat");
                case 62:
                    Process p62 = rt.exec(dir + "/run/Idle62.bat");
                case 61:
                    Process p61 = rt.exec(dir + "/run/Idle61.bat");
                case 60:
                    Process p60 = rt.exec(dir + "/run/Idle60.bat");
                case 59:
                    Process p59 = rt.exec(dir + "/run/Idle59.bat");
                case 58:
                    Process p58 = rt.exec(dir + "/run/Idle58.bat");
                case 57:
                    Process p57 = rt.exec(dir + "/run/Idle57.bat");
                case 56:
                    Process p56 = rt.exec(dir + "/run/Idle56.bat");
                case 55:
                    Process p55 = rt.exec(dir + "/run/Idle55.bat");
                case 54:
                    Process p54 = rt.exec(dir + "/run/Idle54.bat");
                case 53:
                    Process p53 = rt.exec(dir + "/run/Idle53.bat");
                case 52:
                    Process p52 = rt.exec(dir + "/run/Idle52.bat");
                case 51:
                    Process p51 = rt.exec(dir + "/run/Idle51.bat");
                case 50:
                    Process p50 = rt.exec(dir + "/run/Idle50.bat");
                case 49:
                    Process p49 = rt.exec(dir + "/run/Idle49.bat");
                case 48:
                    Process p48 = rt.exec(dir + "/run/Idle48.bat");
                case 47:
                    Process p47 = rt.exec(dir + "/run/Idle47.bat");
                case 46:
                    Process p46 = rt.exec(dir + "/run/Idle46.bat");
                case 45:
                    Process p45 = rt.exec(dir + "/run/Idle45.bat");
                case 44:
                    Process p44 = rt.exec(dir + "/run/Idle44.bat");
                case 43:
                    Process p43 = rt.exec(dir + "/run/Idle43.bat");
                case 42:
                    Process p42 = rt.exec(dir + "/run/Idle42.bat");
                case 41:
                    Process p41 = rt.exec(dir + "/run/Idle41.bat");
                case 40:
                    Process p40 = rt.exec(dir + "/run/Idle40.bat");
                case 39:
                    Process p39 = rt.exec(dir + "/run/Idle39.bat");
                case 38:
                    Process p38 = rt.exec(dir + "/run/Idle38.bat");
                case 37:
                    Process p37 = rt.exec(dir + "/run/Idle37.bat");
                case 36:
                    Process p36 = rt.exec(dir + "/run/Idle36.bat");
                case 35:
                    Process p35 = rt.exec(dir + "/run/Idle35.bat");
                case 34:
                    Process p34 = rt.exec(dir + "/run/Idle34.bat");
                case 33:
                    Process p33 = rt.exec(dir + "/run/Idle33.bat");
                case 32:
                    Process p32 = rt.exec(dir + "/run/Idle32.bat");
                case 31:
                    Process p31 = rt.exec(dir + "/run/Idle31.bat");
                case 30:
                    Process p30 = rt.exec(dir + "/run/Idle30.bat");
                case 29:
                    Process p29 = rt.exec(dir + "/run/Idle29.bat");
                case 28:
                    Process p28 = rt.exec(dir + "/run/Idle28.bat");
                case 27:
                    Process p27 = rt.exec(dir + "/run/Idle27.bat");
                case 26:
                    Process p26 = rt.exec(dir + "/run/Idle26.bat");
                case 25:
                    Process p25 = rt.exec(dir + "/run/Idle25.bat");
                case 24:
                    Process p24 = rt.exec(dir + "/run/Idle24.bat");
                case 23:
                    Process p23 = rt.exec(dir + "/run/Idle23.bat");
                case 22:
                    Process p22 = rt.exec(dir + "/run/Idle22.bat");
                case 21:
                    Process p21 = rt.exec(dir + "/run/Idle21.bat");
                case 20:
                    Process p20 = rt.exec(dir + "/run/Idle20.bat");
                case 19:
                    Process p19 = rt.exec(dir + "/run/Idle19.bat");
                case 18:
                    Process p18 = rt.exec(dir + "/run/Idle18.bat");
                case 17:
                    Process p17 = rt.exec(dir + "/run/Idle17.bat");
                case 16:
                    Process p16 = rt.exec(dir + "/run/Idle16.bat");
                case 15:
                    Process p15 = rt.exec(dir + "/run/Idle15.bat");
                case 14:
                    Process p14 = rt.exec(dir + "/run/Idle14.bat");
                case 13:
                    Process p13 = rt.exec(dir + "/run/Idle13.bat");
                case 12:
                    Process p12 = rt.exec(dir + "/run/Idle12.bat");
                case 11:
                    Process p11 = rt.exec(dir + "/run/Idle11.bat");
                case 10:
                    Process p10 = rt.exec(dir + "/run/Idle10.bat");
                case 9:
                    Process p9 = rt.exec(dir + "/run/Idle9.bat");
                case 8:
                    Process p8 = rt.exec(dir + "/run/Idle8.bat");
                case 7:
                    Process p7 = rt.exec(dir + "/run/Idle7.bat");
                case 6:
                    Process p6 = rt.exec(dir + "/run/Idle6.bat");
                case 5:
                    Process p5 = rt.exec(dir + "/run/Idle5.bat");
                case 4:
                    Process p4 = rt.exec(dir + "/run/Idle4.bat");
                case 3:
                    Process p3 = rt.exec(dir + "/run/Idle3.bat");
                case 2:
                    Process p2 = rt.exec(dir + "/run/Idle2.bat");
                case 1:
                    Process p1 = rt.exec(dir + "/run/Idle1.bat");
                    Thread.sleep(5000);
                    //destroy all Processes here or at destroyProcesses()

                    break;

                default:
                    System.exit(0);

            }

        }

        private void processesAray() {



        }

        private void destroyProcesses() {



        }

    public void actionPerformed(final ActionEvent e) {

        if (boxRun.isSelected()) {

            System.out.println("running!");

            try {

                if (runnableTogether > 0 && runnableTogether < 128) {

                firstEvent1();

                }

                else {

                    System.exit(0);

                }

            }

            catch(Exception ex) {

            }

        }

        else {

            System.out.println("not running!");

        }

        if(e.getSource() == runButton){

            //runnableTogetherString = (runnableTogetherInput.getText());

                runnableTogether = Integer.parseInt(runnableTogetherInput.getText());

                try {

                if (runnableTogether > 0 && runnableTogether < 128) {

                firstEvent1();

                }

                else {

                    System.exit(0);

                }

            }

            catch(Exception ex) {

            }

        }

    }

    private void firstEvent1() throws IOException {
        totalRunnable = runnableTogether*17;
        try {
            if (allSets <= totalRunnable) {
                if (setsRun <= runnableTogether) {
                    Processes();

                    setsRun++;
                    /*do {
                    }while(setsRun <= runnableTogether);*/
                    Thread.sleep(5000);
                    //p1.destroy();  // Does not work right now
                    /*p2.destroy();
                    p3.destroy();
                    p4.destroy();
                    p5.destroy();
                    p6.destroy();
                    p7.destroy();
                    p8.destroy();*/

                }
                allSets = allSets + runnableTogether;
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        TF2_Account_Chief gui = new TF2_Account_Chief();
        gui.launchFrame();

        Container contentPane = f.getContentPane();
        contentPane.add(new TF2_Account_Chief());

        //BGimg = ImageIO.read(new File(dir + "/tf2.jpg"));

    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

        //g.drawImage(BGimg, 0, 0, null);

    }

}
```

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: I was about to mention something about process groups as an alternate solution, but some quick research showed that this would be a platform-dependent solution. (I don't think Windows has process groups, for example.) It's likely that Java doesn't support them either, in that case... Just wanted to throw it into a comment anyway to let you know that such things exist on _some_ platforms (e.g., Linux)...

Comment: This will most likely be a Windows application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create an ArrayList or Processes

```
// Create runtime and array
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
List<Process> processes = new ArrayList<Process>();

swtich(bleh){
....
// Add every process    
case 1:
processes.add(rt.exec("my command 1"));

case 2:
processes.add(rt.exec("my command 2"));
....
case n:
processes.add(rt.exec("my command n"));
}

// Destroy all items in the list, iterating the array
destroyProcesses(processes)
```

Where a basic implementation could be

```
private void destroyProcesses(List<Process> processes){

    if (processes == null)
        return;
    else{
        for (Process thisProcess : processes)
            thisProcess.destroy();

        processes.clear();
    }
}
```

Comment: Except that I am having the cases go from 128 - 1 as I want them to fall through

Comment: I've updated my answer, with some cleanance to the List, since destroying the processes will not clear them from the list.

Comment: @ChristianMeneses If I add the `processes.clear();` part, it does not `destroy()` all of the processes for some reason...

Comment: @ChristianMeneses Also, do you know another way to, instead of "sleeping" a thread, as in `Thread.sleep();` to merely allow the processes to run on another thread and make the new thread sleep like the way I had the default thread sleeping?

Comment: I've edited it with some indentation to show more clarity. The clear() should be executed only after all processes have been destroyed. It is not a part of the iteration.

Comment: @ChristianMeneses I know. But for some odd reason, it does not destroy them all.

Comment: Oh, I just tried to do an edit to clarify the same thing. :)  Incidentally, in this case I'd suggest using a LinkedList instead of an ArrayList since you are appending new item and iterating through the list in order (things LinkedLists are good at) and are not doing any random accesses (which ArrayLists are good at). That's just a minor performance tweak, though, and won't really matter unless your list gets really long or your program is _really_ performance sensitive.